# Boost GIL write_view throws LNK2019 errors

Tags: c++, png, boost-gil

I want to learn how to load, write, ... *.png images with Boost GIL. 
(My programming environment is VS 2019)

The problem is that GIL has problems with saving/loading files. 
It throws many [LNK2019 errors](http://%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X0G--XQ0Wcq0p1qylK_GIiYP7TCnf_ET/view?usp=sharing).

My Code is:

```
boost::gil::rgb8_image_t img(512, 512);
boost::gil::rgb8_pixel_t red(255, 0, 0);
boost::gil::fill_pixels(boost::gil::view(img), red);
boost::gil::write_view("test2.png", boost::gil::const_view(img), boost::gil::png_tag());
             // ^ not only write_view but also read_image
```

This is one of the errors ([all errors here](http://%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X0G--XQ0Wcq0p1qylK_GIiYP7TCnf_ET/view?usp=sharing)):

```
unresolved external symbol _png_create_write_struct referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::gil::writer_backend<class
boost::gil::detail::file_stream_device<struct boost::gil::png_tag>,struct boost::gil::png_tag>::writer_backend<class boost::gil::detail::file_stream_device<struct
boost::gil::png_tag>,struct boost::gil::png_tag>(class boost::gil::detail::file_stream_device<struct boost::gil::png_tag> const &,struct
boost::gil::image_write_info<struct boost::gil::png_tag,class boost::gil::no_log> const &)"
(??0?$writer_backend@V?$file_stream_device@Upng_tag@gil@boost@@@detail@gil@boost@@Upng_tag@34@@gil@boost@@QAE@ABV?$file_stream_
device@Upng_tag@gil@boost@@@detail@12@ABU?$image_write_info@Upng_tag@gil@boost@@Vno_log@23@@12@@Z)
```

Comment: Please include the errors as text in the question.

Comment: @G.M. I added one error (just one out of 37 because these errors are just too long).

Comment: I really don't use boost GIL but I'd guess that particular symbol comes from libpng.so.  Try adding that to the linker command with `-lpng` .

Comment: I set the Configuration to Release and then back to Debug, and now it works...
Now some other issues are appearing that have nothing to do with the Linker errors, but they are still annoying  ╰（‵□′）╯

Comment: It&#39;s not GIL is having problems with saving/loading. It&#39;s not GIL throws the error. It&#39;s linker error due to your project being misconfigured. You just need to learn your IDE of choice how to link your program with additional libraries, namely libpng. p.s. Your question is confusing as it suggest you're hitting GIL bug, what's not the case. I suggest you rephrase it for readers convenience.